# The question about flows and divergence

Tags: partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator

On a recent differential equations exam I had a task to prove some result involving closed flows and curls, something I have never seen before so I have no idea how to solve it and I hoped I would find some help here.

**The question**

Let $f,g,\varphi$ be $C^1$ functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (where $G$ is a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$). If the equation
$$C:=\frac{\partial(\varphi f)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial(\varphi g)}{\partial y}\neq0$$
holds on the whole of $G$, prove that the flow
$$x'(t)=f(x,y),\quad y'(t)=g(x,y)$$
doesn't have closed (periodic) orbits (except maybe equilibriums).

**My attempts**

Generaly, I supposed the opposite: let there be such an orbit, I want to prove that there exists the point where $C=0$. My first attempt was to look for such a point "inside of" the closed orbit (in the area of which the orbit is the boundary), for that I wrongly thought that that whole area is layered in closed orbits and I used linearization in that one equilibrium inside that area. Anyway, that failed. Secondly, I tried looking for that point on the orbit. There, $(f,g)\neq0$ so I tried looking for a strictly positive scalar function $k:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial(kf)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial(kg)}{\partial y}=0$ on the orbit. The flow $x'(t)=(kf)(x,y),\;y'(t)=(kg)(x,y)$ has the same orbits as the original flow. Then, whereever $\varphi/k$ reaches an extremum on the orbit we have that $C=0$ (it could be directly checked). But I couldn't find such $k$.

Comment: **Note: don't look at the link below if you don't want to be given the explicit details of the proof.** Just so you know, this is called the [Bendixson-Dulac criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) or often just Bendixson criterion. Essentially, the proof boils down to integrating $C = \nabla \cdot (\varphi f, \varphi g)$ over the domain $G$, assuming $C > 0$ (or $< 0$), using a particular vector calculus result (notice $C$ written as $\nabla \cdot$ above).

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you Matthew! I checked the theorem now and it seems easy and simple. Shame on me for not trying to use the Green's theorem. Anyway, in the meanwhile I was lucky to actually find a solution and it was different so for other people's curiosity I'll say the idea here. It is to observe the alternate flow $x'=\varphi f$ and $y'=\varphi g$ (which has the same orbits) and apply to the interior of the periodic orbit the Liouville's theorem about change of the volume under flow (which is exactly this divergence which should be $\neq0$).

Comment: Glad to help. Just a suggestion, but you might want to answer your own question in the answer section below and accept it. That way people have access to your solution, they can upvote it and give you more reputation while also helping the math.stackexchange site by removing the question from the open list.